# How many Peltier will be connected to obtain 18V and 1 amps?

Tags: peltier

I am trying to generate electricity through a Peltier. I could supply heat of 120-degree Celcius to the hot side and 0-degree Celsius to the cold side.
I am thinking to use TEC1- 12706 Peltier whose configurations are:

```
Model number: TEC1-12706
Operating Voltage: 12V
Maximum Voltage Umax (V) : 15.4V
Maximum Current Imax (A) : 6A
Maximum Power: 92 W
Maximum Temperature: 138°C
Power Cord: 200mm
```

Though it has been stated I don't a single module will be able to provide 92W (Please correct me if I am wrong)

I want to generate 18 V and 1 amp. I have two queries:

1.How to determine the number of Peltiers required?

2.Is there any other way than connecting them in series to be able to obtain the required power?

Comment: One module generates 92W but you only need 18W? Why would you need more than one? And why do you think the module can't supply 92W?

Comment: I guess, you should connect them in series and then use a buck converter. Probably the efficiency and heat conductivity would determine how much items you have to connect.

Comment: "I want to generate 18V and 1A". From Peltier modules? Rethink your task. At 120C your best chance is probably a steam engine working into a condensor.  120C steam won't give you much pressure but cooling the latter to 0C will produce a pretty good vacuum which is where most of its power will come from : look up the relevant pressures in steam tables.

Answer (score 1):

The specification of the Peltier element list what it can handle when you use it to **displace heat** by applying electrical power to the element.

**If** sufficient measures have been taken to remove the heat (so that the element does not get too hot, it stays below 138°C) then the element can use up to 92 W of electrical power to displace the heat.

These specifications **do not in any way tell you anything** about the Peltier element's capabilities of turning a temperature difference into electricity! Those numbers do no tell you anything at all!!!

Using a Peltier element for cooling is **quite inefficient**, only around 10% - 15% of the electrical energy is actually used for heat displacement (compared with 40–60% achieved by conventional compression-cycle systems). Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_cooling).

**If** the temperature difference to electrical energy conversion would be equally (in)efficient then the maximum power you could generate with one element would be 15 % of 92 W = 14 W.

This is **if** that is the case and I expect that this is **not** the case and that above 14 W is **complete nonsense**. I expect that the temperature difference to electrical energy conversion is **even less efficient** than 10% - 15%.

Have a look at others experimenting with Peltier elements and see how much power they are able to extract. I warn you: it is not a lot. You want 18 W, my guess is that it will be **very expensive** to make a setup that can generate that amount of power. If you would use a solar panel you would get much more power for much less money.

[This is a good video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9aSPopIcKLQ) by Dave of the EEVBlog explaining Peltier TEG Energy harvesting.

Comment: I cannot use solar panel because I have heat source, not sunlight.

Comment: "only around 10% - 15% of the electrical energy is actually used for heat displacement" ->  you misread the meaning of that number in the cited wiki article. In reality they're not nearly so bad since that fraction is as a percent of the ideal Carnot pump, so "efficiency" in this sense can be over 100% for a TEC (more than 1 J pumped per joule of electricity).

Answer (score 0):

Peltiers stack like batteries. Output at 70 degrees 3.5 V per Peltier 640 mA 0.735 mW.